# R: apply function to table and merge the result list

Tags: r, list, merge, lapply

I am sure this question has a simple answer, but I can't find it.

I use sapply to summarize a table with thousands of observations. Each observation contains one of 10 types (coded as "R", "B", etc.) for each column ("ASPRU", "ASPPL" etc.) of the table:

```
        ASPRU ASPBG ASPBY ASPCZ ASPHR ASPMK ASPPL ASPPLA ASPSK ASPSL ASPSR ASPSRA
...      
460     I     -     I     Z     I     I     I      -     -     I     I      I
461     I     -     I     -     I     I     I      -     Z     I     -      I
462     I     -     -     Z     I     -     -      -     -     -     -      -
463     Z     Z     Z     -     Z     -     Z      Z     Z     I     I      Z
477     -     -     -     O     -     -     N      -     -     -     -      -
478     -     -     I     -     -     I     I      -     -     -     I      I
479     -     Z     I     -     I     -     -      -     -     -     I      I
480     -     I     I     I     -     -     -      Z     -     -     -      -
482     -     -     -     -     K     -     -      -     -     -     -      K
483     O     -     -     -     O     -     O      -     -     -     -      O
484     O     -     I     -     -     -     N      O     -     A     -      O
```

I use sapply and table:

```
sapply(colnames(NomSuff), function(x) {t(as.table(table(NomSuff[,x])))})
```

to get a frequency list of the types present for each column. This is a list like this

```
$ASPRU

   -    A    C    I    K    L    N    O    R    S    V    Z    М 
8352  136  115  697   75   92  147  265   24  142   48   61  193 

$ASPBG

   -    A    C    I    K    L    N    O    S    Z    М 
8899  191  119  388   14  128  183  193   93   76   63 

$ASPBY

   -    A    C    I    K    N    O    S    Z    М 
9194   92   85  385   18  160  213   71   60   69
```

etc.

Note that the set of symbols used for each column is different. Now, obviously I want a table like the following with the frequencies for each column combined, i.e.

```
        -       A   C   I   K   L   N   O   S   Z   М   
ASPBG   8899    191 119 388 14  128 183 193 93  76  63  
ASPBY   9194    92  85  385 NA  18  160 213 71  60  69
```

(and better still, with 0 instead of NA).

I can't find a way to do this. I've tried merge in several ways, but I guess the problem is I can't find out how to transform the list in an appropriate format for merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading in your data:

```
df <- read.table(text='ASPRU ASPBG ASPBY ASPCZ ASPHR ASPMK ASPPL ASPPLA ASPSK ASPSL ASPSR ASPSRA
460     I     -     I     Z     I     I     I      -     -     I     I      I
461     I     -     I     -     I     I     I      -     Z     I     -      I
462     I     -     -     Z     I     -     -      -     -     -     -      -
463     Z     Z     Z     -     Z     -     Z      Z     Z     I     I      Z
477     -     -     -     O     -     -     N      -     -     -     -      -
478     -     -     I     -     -     I     I      -     -     -     I      I
479     -     Z     I     -     I     -     -      -     -     -     I      I
480     -     I     I     I     -     -     -      Z     -     -     -      -
482     -     -     -     -     K     -     -      -     -     -     -      K
483     O     -     -     -     O     -     O      -     -     -     -      O
484     O     -     I     -     -     -     N      O     -     A     -      O', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=T)
```

Convert everything to factor, `table`, and `rbind`:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(df, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=c(levels(unlist(df)))))))
```

The result:

```
        -   I   O   Z   K   N   A
ASPRU   5   3   2   1   0   0   0
ASPBG   8   1   0   2   0   0   0
ASPBY   4   6   0   1   0   0   0
ASPCZ   7   1   1   2   0   0   0
ASPHR   4   4   1   1   1   0   0
ASPMK   8   3   0   0   0   0   0
ASPPL   4   3   1   1   0   2   0
ASPPLA  8   0   1   2   0   0   0
ASPSK   9   0   0   2   0   0   0
ASPSL   7   3   0   0   0   0   1
ASPSR   7   4   0   0   0   0   0
ASPSRA  3   4   2   1   1   0   0
```

Comment: Very neat. Thanks a lot! Now I only have to find a function that gives me the inventory of all symbols in df.

Comment: Try `levels(unlist(df))`.

Comment: Thanks, this is really what I was looking for. I updated the answer accordingly.